# Google App Engine: Creating an Ecommerce website

Tags: python, google-app-engine, e-commerce

I'm working on an ecommerce website, using Google App Engine with Python. Now, since its an ecommerce website, we would be having dozens of products displayed, each having its own webpage. Now, my question is, if we have about 400 web pages on our server, won't it make the site pretty heavy and bulky? Won't that affect the user experience?

How can we manage the 400-odd web pages on Google App Engine? Is there something I don't know about making a web application less bulky in spite of hosting multiple web pages on the server?

Comment: If you are thinking that you have to create 400 separate HTML pages for each product you don't. You would create a product page layout and have your backend populate it with data.

Comment: You can manage the pages with any back end you create in one of the many python web frameworks (Django, Flask, Web2Py etc.) And 400 pages is not large or bulky especially since those pages should be mostly formulaic and generated with templates from data.

Comment: IanAuld, can you elaborate more on how to populate my layout product page with custom data for each page?

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi There are a lot of options for something like that. I prefer using Flask myself but it's certainly not the only option. http://flask.pocoo.org/ should help you get an idea of what Flask offers.

Comment: You should finish the GAE tutorial if you haven't done that yet..  I like Flask as well.. and I have a nice starting point for that if you're interested: http://docs.gae-init.appspot.com/tutorial/

Comment: Thanks! I'll look forward to learning Flask now. Also, can't I do the same in the webapp2 framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use webapp2 framework and fetch product info from the datastore and render it with a template. You make an entity for your product e.g.

```
class Product(db.Model):

    tags = db.ListProperty(db.Category)
    category = db.CategoryProperty(verbose_name='Category')
    title = db.StringProperty(verbose_name='title')  # required
    text = db.TextProperty(verbose_name='text')
```

Then you have a handler class using webapp2, flask, bottle or similar to fetch your product data and render it with for instance the jinja 2 templating engine.

```
class ProductHandler(BaseHandler):

    def get_product(self, key):
        data = memcache.get(key)
        if data is not None:
            return data
        else:
            data = Product.get_by_id(long(key))
            memcache.add(key, data, 6000)
            return data

    def get(self, id, html):
        product= self.get_product(id)
        if not product:
            self.error(404)
            return

        self.render_jinja(
            'view_product',
            product=product)
```

Then in your template you can use the variables on the view_product.html e.g.

```
 {{product.title}
```

And the routing is done with a config object for webapp2 (this will be different if you use flask or bottle but if you use flask or bottle you can't leverage webapp2's extras such as User models and i18n)

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/view/(\d+)(\.html?)?', ProductHandler),
```